# Opening PDF's in new tabs instead of windows is not working in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Continuous Release), Version 2019.021.20056

I've the open in tabs instead of windows feature selected, yet whenever I double click and open a PDF, it opens in a separate window, rather than a separate tab.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro (64bit)

[image]

Comment: Reinstall acrobat reader. By default it opens in tabs and not windows.

Answer (score 1):

Does not happen in an older Pro version, so this is probably a new bug in
Acrobat Reader.

Some suggestions:

- See if an update to Acrobat Reader is available
- Uninstall completely Acrobat Reader using
  [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/),
  then reinstall
- Check the command used to launch Acrobat in registry key
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\command`
  My parameters are `/u "%1"`
- Signal the problem to Adobe as indicated in the
  [Adobe Help Center](https://helpx.adobe.com/support.html)
- Workaround : Use an
  [alternate PDF reader](https://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-reader/),
  for example
  [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/).

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings > Apps > Under Apps & features find Adobe Acrobat DC and click on it >> then click on Modify >  Select Repair and click next and proceed.

This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Working here with same DC version & Win10 (Enterprise LTSB v1607). My General screen looks the same too.

1. Have you tried unchecking `Open documents as new tabs in the same
   window...` clicking OK, close all Adobe windows, open again, re-check that & test?
2. Have you tried reinstalling or repairing the installation?
3. What happens when you double-click a second PDF file? I've had some users where nothing happens that I am still troubleshooting